# removing/stopping a specific mkAnnotationView from being reused

Tags: cocoa-touch, android-mapview, mkannotationview

I've been playing around with the MapKit and came across a puzzling scenario that i'm not creative/knowledgable enough to work my way around of. In my map application, I have a mapView that I would like to drop pins onto. My dilema arrises from the fact that mapView reuses it's annotationViews. what I would idealy like to do, is press a button, then drop a draggable *temporary* pin in order to record a location that a user would like to use. This annotation's view does not have a rightCallOutAccesoryView however. When it comes time to drop a legitimate pin, iIneed to remove the temporary pin from the mapView and then add legitamate one with the old pin's coordinates. Apparently, If I drop the *legit* Pin first, and then remove *temp* Pin, the mapView still somehow manages to reuse the annotationView of the tempPin that does not have the rightCallOutAccesoryView when infact i just want a new one for the *legit* Pin that does have one. can anyone tell me how this could be done?

What I need to do in a nut shell, is remove an annotation, and then make a new one without reusing the old pin's annotationView...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you get anywhere with this? I am trying to find a solution to the same problem at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's been nearly  year since I've asked this question but I remember what my problem was, and the solution I ended up implementing was that I always change the attributes of the current pin, without ever removing them then re-adding them. I changed it's view and changed the annotation it used, and next time I needed a temp pin, I allocated a new one and used that one until it's position was fixed and calloutaccesoryview was enabled..

Hope this technique helps people in the future.